# Last Digit of $x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + \cdots + x^{p-1} + x^p$

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, geometric-series

> Given $x$ and $p$. Find the last digit of $x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + \cdots + x^{p-1} + x^p$

I need a general formula. I can find that the sum is equal to
$\dfrac{x^{p+1}-1}{x-1}$
But how to find the last digit.

**P.S**: $x\leq 999999$ and $p \leq 10^{15}$

Comment: How did you get that expression for the sum?

Comment: You only need the last digit of any $x$ (for example, if $x=999999$ then you may calculate the above series with $9$).

Comment: @carmichael561 Wolframalpha

Comment: @barakmanos But what is about $p$?

Comment: @RezwanArefin wouldn't the sum just be $\frac{1-x^{p+1}}{1-x}$? Is it not a geometric series? EDIT: Sorry, I see you just changed it.

Comment: @Αδριανός I got the first expression from Wolfram-alpha. :)

Comment: @RezwanArefin Goes to show that computers don't always get the most beautiful or simplest answer! I guess mathematicians still have the upper hand....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $x>0$.

Let $d$ denote the last digit of the series.

You can split the answer into $10$ different cases.

---

The following cases are rather simple:

- $x\equiv0\pmod{10} \implies d=1$
- $x\equiv1\pmod{10} \implies d=(1+p)\bmod{10}$
- $x\equiv4\pmod{10} \implies d=1+4(p\bmod{2})$
- $x\equiv5\pmod{10} \implies d=1+5(p\bmod{2})$
- $x\equiv9\pmod{10} \implies d=1-1(p\bmod{2})$

---

The following cases are a little more complicated:

- $x\equiv2\pmod{10} \implies d=\frac{-4(p\bmod{4})^3+15(p\bmod{4})^2-5(p\bmod{4})+3}{3}$
- $x\equiv3\pmod{10} \implies d=\frac{+1(p\bmod{4})^3-9(p\bmod{4})^2+17(p\bmod{4})+3}{3}$
- $x\equiv6\pmod{10} \implies d=\frac{-5(p\bmod{5})^4+40(p\bmod{5})^3-100(p\bmod{5})^2+83(p\bmod{5})+3}{3}$
- $x\equiv7\pmod{10} \implies d=\frac{+1(p\bmod{4})^3-15(p\bmod{4})^2+35(p\bmod{4})+3}{3}$
- $x\equiv8\pmod{10} \implies d=\frac{+11(p\bmod{4})^3-54(p\bmod{4})^2+67(p\bmod{4})+3}{3}$

Comment: @RezwanArefin: You need to find the "cycle $\bmod{10}$" of each case. For example, the "cycle $\bmod{10}$" of $2$ is $4$, as $2^n\equiv2^{n+4}\pmod{10}$.

Comment: Amazing solution :) But how did you get these....

Comment: @RezwanArefin: Thanks :) The simple cases... well, they were simply simple. For the complicated ones, I calculated the cycle, found the unit digit in each step, and then calculated the interpolation polynomial. For example, When $x\equiv2\pmod{10}$, the cycle is $1,3,7,5$, so I [interpolated $[0,1],[1,3],[2,7],[3,5]$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Interpolate%28[0,1],[1,3],[2,7],[3,5]%29).

Answer (score 1):

We'll work it out mod 5 and mod 2. We'll assume $p > 2$.

Mod 2, we have $x^i \equiv x$ for all $i$, except for $x^0$. Therefore the parity of the sum is just the same as the opposite of that of $x$ [unless $p=2$].

Mod 5: if $x \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ then the result is certain to be $1$ mod $5$. Otherwise, $x^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, so we just have lots of expressions $1+x+x^2+x^3$ all added together; this is $4$ if $x \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, and $0$ otherwise.

Hence:

- If $x$ is $0$ mod 5, the result is 1 mod 5.
- If $x$ isn't 1 mod 5, we'll get $1+x \pmod{5}$ if $p$ is $1$ mod 4, and $1+x+x^2+x^3 = 0$ if $p$ is $3$ mod 4.
- If $x$ is 1 mod 5, we'll get $-(p-1)/4 + (1+x) \pmod{5}$ if $p$ is $1$ mod 4, and $-(p+1)/4 \pmod{5}$ if $p$ is $3$ mod 4.

These together are enough to assemble the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s = \sum_{k=0}^{p}x^k$. Calculate $0 \leq a_1, a_2 < 5$, where
$$
a_1 \equiv s \pmod 2 \\
a_2 \equiv s \pmod 5
$$

$a_1$ is easy. If $x \equiv_2 0$, then $a_1 = 1$, else $a_1 \equiv_2 (1+p)$, cause it's $1 + 1^1 + 1^2 + 1^3 + \dots + 1^p$.

$a_2$ isn't harder, $x \equiv_5 0, 1$ are same. For $2, 3, 4$ you can easily observe regularity. Eg.
$$
x \equiv_5 2 \Longrightarrow\\ s \equiv_5
1 + 2^1 + 2^2 + \dots + 2^{p} \equiv_5 \\
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + \dots + 2^{p} \equiv_5 \\
1 + 2 + 4 + 3 + 1 + 2 \dots + 2^{p} \equiv_5\\
(1 + 2 + 4 + 3) + 1 + 2 \dots + 2^{p} \equiv_5\\
2 \cdot 5 + 1 + 2 \dots + 2^{p}
$$

If you know $a_1, a_2$ you can use [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), to calculate number $r \equiv_{10} s$ and it's last digit.